# "pile" columns on top of each other

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
a = rnorm(10,10,10)

b = rnorm(10, 6, 7)

c = rnorm( 10, 5, 5)

d = data.frame(a,b,c)

 head(d)
           a          b          c
1 18.3615091 -1.1253320  0.3403199
2  4.9365020  2.4014072 -3.5771919
3 12.5686200  0.7474177 -4.6788551
4  0.1913607 -0.6456205  3.8693564
5  9.1718179 16.1776224  8.1820692
6 18.3757202  4.1313655 -0.4195688
```

Is it possible to convert this data set into a single column of data (i.e. 1 column and 30 rows)?

I tried a few ways:

```
#first way
d = data.frame(a + b + c)

#second way

d = cbind(a,b,c)

#third way 

d = rbind(a,b,c)
```

But nothing seems to work.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Try `stack(d)`...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this code d = stack(a,b,c) and got the following error:

Comment: Error in data.frame(values = unlist(unname(x)), ind, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 0
In addition: Warning message:
In if (drop) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: stack the data frame `d`, not each vector...i.e. `stack(d)`

Comment: Or from the vectors directly... `data.frame(c(a, b, c))`

Comment: if you post your answer, I can accept it as the correct answer! thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `stack` or `reshape2::melt` or `tidyr::pivot_longer`

```
stack(d)
reshape2::melt(d)
tidyr::pivot_longer(c(a,b,c))
```

will work.

Answer (score 2):

You may first convert the dataframe to a matrix. Matrices in R are stored in [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), so(*) if you convert the matrix to a vector, you will get the stacked columns as a vector:

```
as.vector(as.matrix(d))
```

If you want dataframe instead:

```
data.frame(stack = as.vector(as.matrix(d)))
```

---

(*) In R a matrix is just a vector with a dimension attribute, and the data is stored in column-major order in the vector. For instance:

```
structure(1:4, dim = c(2, 2))

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

When you convert a matrix to a vector, you simply remove the dimension.

```
as.vector(.Last.value)

[1] 1 2 3 4
```